# ProGuard rules for Kotlin reflection

Tags: android, reflection, proguard, kotlin

Here's a very simple class:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val prop: String = "test"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        Log.d("MainActivity", ::prop.name)
    }

}
```

If I run this application with ProGuard using the following rules:

```
-dontwarn kotlin.**
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.events.*
-dontwarn org.jetbrains.kotlin.di.InjectorForRuntimeDescriptorLoader
```

I get this exception:

```
a.d.g: Property 'prop' not resolved in class com.cypressworks.kotlinreflectionproguard.MainActivity
```

Which ProGuard rules do I need to apply to make it work?

Comment: Did you have a successful answer to this question?

Comment: Not really, the issue is tracked here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7652. However, property reflection now works without `kotlin-reflect.jar` and doesn't require any proguard rules.

Answer (score 1):

If ProGuard is removing your attribute, the `dontwarn` rule will only hide the warning messages. What you need is to actually tell ProGuard to keep it.

One possible way could be:

```
-keepclassmembers public class com.cypressworks.kotlinreflectionproguard.** {
    public * *;
}
```